# How to manage multi-tenant request and directs the request to targets

Tags: .net, kubernetes, multi-tenant, ocelot

We have designed a multi-tenant application and deployed this on AWS, as of now for each tenant an instance of application is deployed on different node managed by EKS cluster and using kubernates namespace we are managing tenant separation and isolation at application level and for each tenant we have different database.

Now, I am not able to figure out, how I can manage the request from tenant and directs it to respective clusters and namespaces running on some ip and port.

I want to expose an end point like https://example.com
and want to redirects request to different ip and port among the clusters.

- client1 --> https://example.com:3100 (application will be loaded running on tenant1 namespace UI + backend))
- client2 --> https://example.com:3200
- client3 --> https://example.com:3300

NOTE: UI is in Angular , Backend is in DotNet which us using ocelot gateway and UI is bundled in the gateway.

[image]

can anyone please propose me some idea ?

Comment: You can use Aws API Gateway to forward requests and check the health status.

Comment: @RichardRublev any documentation would help me hear . Please note my enpoints are website which is bundled in dot net gateway and using ocelots